# nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use) on mac

Tags: macos, nginx

I'm new to Nginx and had some trouble here.

I'm using **Mac OS** and `nginx version: nginx/1.17.7`.

The first time I downloaded Nginx was some time ago. At that time, everything ran perfectly. Then When I played around with `nginx.conf`, I messed it up somehow. So, when I restarted learning Nginx today, I removed all the files I had before and reinstalled it through homebrew. Then the issue I wished someone could help me with popped out.

After initializing Nginx, I got this error

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

I searched for this issue online. There were a lot of answers, but either the solutions were for Linux not Mac, or they just couldn't work.

One of the most promising answers I'd found was to kill the `processes` that were sort of using the port. *By the way, even though I had this error, I could access the page `localhost:8080`, but it was `403 Forbidden page`.* Then I tried a command on `Terminal`: `ps ax -o pid,ppid,%cpu,vsz,wchan,command|egrep '(nginx|PID)'` ([source](https://serverfault.com/questions/548740/nginx-error-log-reports-bind-to-0-0-0-080-failed-48-address-already-in-use))

This was the output:

```
  PID  PPID  %CPU      VSZ WCHAN  COMMAND
21827     1   0.0  4291640 -      nginx: master process nginx
21828 21827   0.0  4301348 -      nginx: worker process
21831 93689   0.0  4267768 -      egrep (nginx|PID)
```

I didn't (still don't) understand what this told, so I tried to kill all of them through `kill -9 <PID>`, i.e. `kill -9 21827`, `kill -9 21828`, and `kill -9 21831`.

Then I got an error: `-bash: kill: (21827) - Operation not permitted`. I just thought maybe `sudo` could solve this, so I tried `sudo kill -9 21827`. And this time **it worked**. I killed all the processes but the third one. When I attempted to `sudo kill -9 21831`, I got `No such process`. Then I found out it was because the `PID` of this process was **changing all the time** for some reason, so if I didn't catch the exact PID of the process at that exact moment I couldn't kill it. Then I left it there like that.

Then I tried to run `nginx` on `Terminal`. This was the output:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

This time I didn't find an answer that had the potential to solve this problem... So I tried to **restart nginx** through the command `sudo nginx -s stop && sudo nginx` ([source](https://serverfault.com/questions/225948/how-to-restart-nginx-on-mac-os-x)) But this didn't work. It reported `nginx: [alert] kill(21827, 15) failed (3: No such process)`. So I tried another answer provided in the same source: `brew services list` and then `brew services start nginx`.

But still I got `nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)`.

Now I don't know how to solve this problem. Also I tried to reinstall nginx by homebrew. But the previous processes would as they did popped out.

Beside, I tried this command as well: `ps aux | grep nginx`. This gave me three processes before I killed processes. After all these, I got just

```
apple            22922   0.0  0.0  4267768    832 s003  S+    3:09AM   0:00.00 grep nginx
```

Not sure what this could tell.

Could any help what was going wrong here? Alternatively, could you share the correct initial steps to follow to get Nginx running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot going on here. First, The Mac OS is a close relative of Linux. Many Linux solutions/commands will work natively on your Mac. Those that don't can generally be modified to make them work. In some cases you may need to install additional command-line tools that are not installed by default in the Mac OS.

Second, `ps` is short for "process status". As the name suggests, it is a command that reports the status of processes running on your machine (that your permissions allow you to see). It is certainly possible, and at times may be necessary, to use `kill` to terminate processes. But, I wouldn't recommend it if you don't know what you're doing. As you discovered, depending on your OS permissions/setup you may need to use `sudo` to override. Probably better to rely on the nginx commands for starting and stopping a running nginx server. One thing this will do is allow these actions to be performed "gracefully", which is to say "cleanly" and "without unintended side effects". More on that later.

The reason the PID kept changing for the third process in your `ps` output is because that process was the `egrep` process itself being reported. Every time you run the command, a new `egrep` command is executed and gets its own sparkly new PID.

Another thing to note in your `ps` output: there are 2 `nginx` processes. One is a master, the other a worker. As long as the master is running, you can kill the worker process over and over, and the master process will spawn a new worker process (with another new PID). The documentation says "The main purpose of the master process is to read and evaluate configuration files, as well as maintain the worker processes."

Now, it sounds like another process is already using port 8080. You can discover what that process is by running this command:

`lsof -nPL -iTCP:8080`

Depending on what the `lsof` command reports back, you may be able to quit the program or terminate the process using the reported `PID`. If, for some reason, you can't or don't want to terminate the offending process, then you will have to change the configuration for `nginx`.

As the error messages suggest, you now have a permissions issue with the file `/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid` that is preventing `nginx` from starting. That file contains the PID that was given to the `nginx` process when it was started. When you issue the command `nginx -s stop`, it is trying to read the previously assigned PID from that file. When it can't, it fails with the error message you are seeing.

An unintended side effect of using `kill` to terminate the `nginx` processes is that they did not get a chance to clean up after themselves. One thing that they do on shutdown is remove the `nginx.pid` file that contained the previously assigned PID. The good news is that if that file doesn't exist, then `nginx` will create a new one. So all you have to do is run `sudo rm /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid` and then run `nginx`.

Comment: I looked at the steps you mentioned but even after deleting nginx.pid I can neither stop nginx nor restart. Also when I run "sudo nginx -s stop" I get "nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.21.6_1/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
"

Comment: ..........TL;DR

Answer (score 3):

Is it because you silently started nginx somewhere and it's already running? You can either stop that or kill the processes found via `ps -ef | grep nginx`.

Answer (score 1):

I also had exactly same problem, I tried everything else but luckily force quitting nginx processes in network tab of Activity Monitor fixed my issue in mac.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Run **top** in your the terminal and search for the running **NGINX** process. Alternatively press [COMMAND] + [SPACE] and type `activity` and open ***Activity Monitor*** and search for **NGINX** there.
Find the running instance of **NGINX** in the list of active process, it's run under the **root** user and make a note of it's **PID** number.

Write that **PID** number into `/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid` file on its own on the first line of the `nginx.pid` file.
Open `/usr/local/config/nginx.conf` and uncommect the the line:
`pid log/nginx.pid`

Even if you have stopped **NGINX** already stopped it again before STOP it again because now it can do it correctly with the **PID** number `sudo nginx -s stop` and then start it again `sudo nginx`
It should start without issue, if not look for other running instances and repeat.

### Reason it's happening

**Nginx** can't stop it's own process because it doesn't know it's processes **PID** number of the running instance and that instance is bound to the relative port blocking a second **Nginx** instances binding to that same port.

This happened on MacOS Ventura. It was a fresh install of **Nginx** and I was still configuring the `/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.conf` file. It happened because I changed the location of the **PID** file in the **NGINX** config file while **NGINX** was running and therefore it couldn't stop itself because it didn't know where to find the **PID** number of it's own process.
Therefore, even if you haven't already set the **PID** file location in the `/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.conf` file do it now so **NGINX** can find its **PID** number and stop itself correctly in future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use 'pgrep nginx' to get pid no. and kill it with 'kill -9 <pid>'.